# Multilingual fan pages

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've got an algorism that is calling the Graph API to grab the posts of fan pages that we don’t have in our database (to make statistics on them).

We call the Graph API with an app token, and with “normal” fan pages (no located posts), we don’t have any problems, we correctly have all posts.

But when we try to grab country located posts, the Graph API returns to us nothing. I think it’s due to the fact that an application don’t have a language (by default), so to resolve that, I take the access token of an admin of the page and then the Graph API give me all the data I need.

My question is simple : Is there a way to grab country located data with app token ?

Thank you for your answers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you `own` that page, no, there is no way. This would create a privacy issue where the Graph API can be used to display otherwise restricted content. This applies to age and alcohol restrictions as well.

Comment: Yes, you're right, i have to use a user access token in order to have posts from pages which are alcohol pages. But i would hope that for country problems there is a solution ...

Comment: Unfortunately, there isn't. The content is geographically restricted for a reason and it can't be leaked through the Graph API. That would defeat the purpose.

Comment: Hi everybody, here is the answer of a facebook developper : 
“The short answer to your client's question is no. There is no way to grab country located data within an app access token. Once a user puts country restriction information on a page then the only way to access this information is using an user access token. It is the same for age restrictions.”